# Разбить и цикл не получается

Tags: php

Кусочек кода  $tovar['*ATTRIBUTES*'] нужно два раза разбить строку по explode и собрать в мой вариант. Разбить то я смог ) но проблема не могу сделать это все с foreach

Есть строка

Автопилот: Нет |Время полёта: 8 мин|Длина: 166 мм|Ширина: 166 мм|Видеокамера: Нет

Сначала разбить на | , а потом уже на :

и собрать так

Характеристики|Автопилот:|Нет 
Характеристики|Время полёта:|8 мин
Характеристики|Длина:|166 мм
Характеристики|Ширина:|166 мм
Характеристики|Видеокамера:|Нет

```
 foreach($data as $a_product) {

    $tovar['_ATTRIBUTES_'] = $data[16];

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$res = [];
$str = "Автопилот: Нет |Время полёта: 8 мин|Длина: 166 мм|Ширина: 166 мм|Видеокамера: Нет";
$arr1 = explode("|", $str);
foreach ($arr1 as $i) {
  list($key, $value) = explode(": ", $i);
  $res[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($res)
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Автопилот] => Нет 
    [Время полёта] => 8 мин
    [Длина] => 166 мм
    [Ширина] => 166 мм
    [Видеокамера] => Нет
)
```

Надеюсь, правильно понял проблему и стало легче разобраться.

P.S. Собрать, чтоб прямо как в вопросе:

```
foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
    printf("Характеристики|%s:|%s ", $key, $value);
}
```

Output:

```
Характеристики|Автопилот:|Нет  Характеристики|Время полёта:|8 мин Характеристики|Длина:|166 мм Характеристики|Ширина:|166 мм Характеристики|Видеокамера:|Нет
```

Comment: А собрать как лучше ?) Не хочу наглеть действительно интересно как правильней

Comment: дополнил ответ.